# What is the libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib that I find inside my app bundle?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build

Is there any documentation for it?

PS: S.O. apparently doesn't like very simple and very clear questions so I'm forced to add this pointless Post scriptum. thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a bug in Xcodes Commandline Tools (new in Xcode 8).

> If you use Swift programming language, and you use the xcodebuild command line tool to build your apps, xcodebuild may add a file whose name is “libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib” to your app bundle.

From [here](https://medium.com/@zonble/upgrade-to-xcode-8-716cde2bb19d)